# Convert decimal to latitude and longitude

Tags: algorithm, delphi, math

I have a GPS device which sends data to my server, I need to convert the decimal values that the device sends into latitude and longitude. I am bad at math so all my attempts failed, here are the specs:

**Latitude**

Occupy 4 bytes, representing the latitude value.

Number range is from 0 to 162000000, which represents the range form 0°to 90°.
Unit: 1/500 second Conversion method:

A) Convert the latitude (degrees, minutes) data from GPS module into a new form which represents the value only in minutes;

B Multiply the converted value by 30000, and then transform the result to hexadecimal number

For example22°32.7658′,（22×60＋32.7658）×30000=40582974, then convert it to hexadecimal number 0x02 0x6B 0x3F 0x3E

**Longitude**

Occupy 4 bytes, representing the longitude value of location data. Number ranges from 0 to 324000000, representing the range form 0°to 180°.Unit: 1/500 seconds, Conversion method is the same as latitude’s.

I came up with this function but it doesn't seem to work:

```
procedure GetDegree(const numar : DWORD; out min,sec : Extended);
var
  eu : Extended;
begin
  eu :=  numar / 30000;
  min := Trunc(eu / 60);
  sec := eu - min * 60;
end;
```

Comment: Why do you say it doesn't work?  What is expected vs. actual output?

Comment: @Destan Not a valid latitude coordonate!

Comment: @opc0de I meant something along these lines would greatly improve your question: "When calling `GetDegree(324032,M,S)` I get `M=321` and `S=12`, but the correct output should be `M=1` and `S=33`."

Comment: There's something wrong with your explanation -- latitudes range over [-90deg,+90deg] and longitudes over (-180,+180].  You seem only to have considered the +ve halves of these ranges.  Or have you omitted to tell us that the representations are signed ?

Comment: You calculation seems correct. Can you give a sample input and the wrong output that you are getting.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark these are extracted from the device's documentation.

Comment: @opc0de: so how does the device represent -ve latitudes and longitudes ?

Comment: In fact 324032 corresponds to 0 deg, 10 min, 48 seconds. Your calculations all seem wrong.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`numar` is specified in 1/500th of a second. So, the following equations hold:

```
num/500 = seconds
num/500/60 = minutes
num/500/60/60 = degrees
```

I would calculate it all like this:

```
var
  degrees, minutes, seconds: Integer;
....
  degrees := num div (500*60*60);
  minutes := num div (500*60) - degrees*60;
  seconds := num div 500 - minutes*60 - degrees*60*60;
```

If you need to calculate the fractional part of seconds then do it like this. Note that there's simply no need for `Extended` here.

```
var
  degrees, minutes: Integer;
  seconds: Double;
....
  degrees := num div (500*60*60);
  minutes := num div (500*60) - degrees*60;
  seconds := num/500 - minutes*60 - degrees*60*60;
```

Plug your value of 40582974 into these formula and the results are:

```
degrees: 22
minutes: 32
seconds: 45
```

Judging from comments what you actually want is degrees as an integer and minutes as a floating point. That you can do like this:

```
var
  degrees: Integer;
  minutes: Double;
....
  degrees := num div (500*60*60);
  minutes := num/(500*60) - degrees*60;
```

Plug your value of 40582974 into these formula and the results are:

```
degrees: 22
minutes: 32.7658
```

Comment: +1 just so you know, english-romanian: number=numar; degrees=grade; minutes=minute; seconds=secunde; ^_^

Comment: for the number 40582974 i should get 22°32.7658′ but running the function i get 22°32.45.948′

Comment: That's because 32.7658 has folder the seconds up into a decimal fraction of minutes. 45.948/60 = .7658. Your question does need more clarity. What do you want? Degrees, minutes and seconds? Or degrees and minutes?

Comment: I've got all the bases covered now in the answer. Anyway, I think there is enough explanation there for you to take it forward.